# Ajax call via POST not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, prototypejs

I have a lil problem with an AJAX request.

We have a lil PHP, JavaScript application (Website). The application is running fine on all desktop browsers + on our old MDE's (some Windows CE6 MDE). Now on our new Motorola MC9200 (Windows Embedded Compact 7 formerly CE7) it's not working anymore.

The problem is some small JavaScript function. It disables the buttons/input fields, starts a Ajax.Request (prototype 1.72 but I tested jQuery 1.11.1 too), does something on the database and when everything went right it is refreshing the site via window.location. This function isn't working always on the new devices. Sometimes it does, sometimes not.

simplified code:

```
function loadSite(siteName) {
  disableForm();
  var parameters = {
    /* SOME PARAMETERS */
  };

  new Ajax.Request('ajax/ajax_db_execute.php', {
     method: 'post',
     parameters: parameters,
     onSuccess: callbackFunc
  });
}

function callbackFunc(transport) {
  response = transport.responseText.evalJSON(true);
  if(response.retcode === 0) {
    window.location = "start.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>";
  } else {
    show_error_box(response.errortext);
      enableForm();
  }
}
```

I tried to output the response in the callbackFunc but that function wasn't even called. Next thing I tried was to put some alert at the end of the loadSite function, it was fired everytime. I already checked the parameters and they look fine too.

After that I put some simple fwrite in the php file. It looks like that file isn't even called sometimes. So the question is why?

By changing the method to 'get' I couldn't reproduce the problem and everything is working fine. Problem about that is that I don't want to use get + some parameters might be too long for get to handle.

The parameters in that example were just some simple integers and strings. Does anyone have an idea what might cause the problem and some workaround?

Comment: In Firefox with firebug or chrome press f12 to open the developer tools or firebug. Check the console for errors and it should show any xhr requests as well

Comment: There are no errors. As I said it runs without any problems in any other browser.

Comment: are you calling `loadSite()` after the DOM is ready? `document.observe('dom:loaded',function(){ })` in PrototypeJS and `$(document).ready(function(){ })` in jQuery

Comment: I'm not using `document.observe('dom:loaded')`, will try that tomorrow but I'm pretty sure the dom is ready. Its a small site (menu) with 4-5 buttons on it, nothing more and its not like I'm spamming the buttons during page load but I'll give `dom:loaded` a try. I'm still wondering why this problem only occurs while using POST and its working with GET.

Comment: Just tried `document.observe`. Didn't help. I set a flag `ready` to true in the function and displaying the flag inside the `loadSite` function, it was already ready, even if the site change didn't work.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that your post request response is not synchronized. So please use setTimeout function in your post callback like that

`setTimeout(function(transport) {
     response = transport.responseText.evalJSON(true);
         if(response.retcode === 0) {
             window.location = "start.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>";
         } 
         else
         {
            show_error_box(response.errortext);
            enableForm();
         }
    }, 3000);`

Comment: The whole point of a callback is to avoid this kind of thing. `callbackFunc` invoked only if the request is successful. Wrapping it in a timeout is wrong.